# Reason for sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

Tags: java, native

I have the following method,

```
 private void addToContainer(DefaultFormBuilder build) {

            /* Build the UI*/ 
            //The UI is built by reading from an XML.   

                /* Add items to Array list */
                arrayList.add(views); //views is JComponent

            } catch (Exception e) {                 
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

From **jstack:**

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=10 tid=0x00007f63a8742800 nid=0x7f9b waiting on condition [0x00007f63a465c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007dddec5f8> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:994)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:236)
    at com.test.addToContainer(test.java:450)
```

Am not sure what is going wrong in this method. Adding views to arrayList can cause this problem?

**Expected** : After this method executes an UI will be launched. However it is not launched in this scenario. Am not getting this error always but very rarely seen.(so far i have faced it only once)

Am new to this please help.

Comment: You might not have posted the full source-code for method `addToContainer`?  Are you using a `CountDownLatch`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WAITING at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241335/waiting-at-sun-misc-unsafe-parknative-method)