# Java ExecutorService - threads in waiting state

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Use Case: Create a new thread every time I need to process a job.

Current Implementation: I am using Executor Service with fixed size thread pool, of say 50. For every job, I submit a new thread to executor service.

Issue: Once the job is completed, the threads do not die and go into waiting state. (waiting at sun.misc.unsafe.park)

Analysis: As per this link ([WAITING at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241335/waiting-at-sun-misc-unsafe-parknative-method)) and other sources on the net, this is a valid scenario, and the threads go into waiting state, waiting for some task to be given to them.

Question: From Java mission control, I am able to deduce that the threads are not using any resources and are not in dead lock. So that is good. But consider a time frame when lots of jobs are submitted and all 50 threads in the pool were instantiated. And after that all the 50 threads are going to be alive even though the job submission rate might have decreased. I cannot shut down the executor service also, since it needs to be alive forever waiting for jobs to be submitted. 
If I create, normal threads, I see that the threads die after their job is done. But in that case there is no tab in the max amount of threads being created. So in a peak time, we may run into a situation where more threads are created than what the JVM can handle.

How can this scenario be handled in the best possible way. Should we ignore the threads being in the waiting state or should I go for any other implementation.

The behavior that I am trying to implement is more like autoscaling. Span more servers(threads in this case)during peak time. And terminate the extra servers and maintain a minimum server count when the load is not that high.

Comment: Isn't that the expected behavior of an object pool?

Comment: It may be the default behavior of thread pool. But in my case, all threads become active during a peak time, after which they are always in waiting state, after which only few will be used at a time. So wanted to know if there are any other settings for the Executor Service that can be used.  Or any other  implementations which would solve this scenario.

Comment: If you want a new thread per job, why are you using an `ExecutorService` at all? And if you don't, why is that the first thing you say?

Comment: @EJP.. If I were to create a new Thread per job, using new Thread(new My Runnable()).start.. then how do I keep tab on the max threads created during peak times. wouldn't there be a scenario where exception is throw as  max resources are reached.. That is why I am trying to use the thread creation framework provided by concurrent package. My requirement is to handle all jobs by creating threads but terminate the threads if they don't receive any jobs in say 'n' milliseconds. More like the autoscaling feature, where you span more servers during peak time and shut down them when not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And after that all the 50 threads are going to be alive even though the job submission rate might have decreased. I cannot shut down the executor service also, since it needs to be alive forever waiting for jobs to be submitted.

...

> How can this scenario be handled in the best possible way. Should we ignore the threads being in the waiting state or should I go for any other implementation.

I think the answer is, you should ignore them.  Threads are pretty darn efficient these days and certainly 50 dormant threads aren't going to affect the runtime of your application in any way.  It would be different if you are talking about a much large number of threads or a whole series of different thread pools all hanging around.

That said, as mentioned, if you want your threads to timeout then you will need to specify a different "core" number of threads (how many should always be running) than the "max" (maximum number that the pool can grow too) and how long the threads should start dormant before they should exit to keep the thread count down at the "core" number.  The problem with this is that then you'll need to have a fixed size job queue otherwise the 2nd thread will never be created.  That's (unfortunately) how the `ThreadPoolExecutor` works.

If you have a different core and max thread numbers and you are submitting a large number of jobs to your thread-pool then you'll need to block the producer else the jobs will be rejected by the queue if it fills up.

Something like:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAX_POOL_SIZE,
    60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(MAX_QUEUE_SIZE));
// need to say what to do if the queue is full
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
     public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
          // this will block the caller if the queue is full
          executor.getQueue().put(r);
     }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please tell me if this (https://stackoverflow.com/q/59231602) could be related?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and set its `keepAliveTime` attribute via any one of its constructors.

Comment: But Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int n), which I am using, in turn uses ThreadPoolExecutor with a KeepAliveTime of 0. So  we don't have to explicitly use ThreadPoolExecutor in the implementation. Also in this case, when the keepAliveTime is zero, I would expect the threads to die immediately which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). However it won't do what you expect it to do. Following constructor can be used to create a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

[ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue workQueue)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor(int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue))

Let me break down it's behavior as documented. When a task is submitted

1. If `poolSize` is less than `corePoolSize`, a new thread is created, even if there are idle threads.
2. If `poolSize` is equal to the `corePoolSize` then task is added to the queue. It won't create new threads until queue is exhausted.
3. if `workQueue` is exhausted then new thread is created till `poolSize` becomes `maximumPoolSize`.
4. If `poolSize` is equal to the `maximumPoolSize` throw [RejectedExecutionException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html)

So now suppose we set core size to 5, max size to 10 and submit 100 tasks. Nothing will happen if we created our pool object with the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class. As pools created by it use [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), with default constructor, which sets the queue capacity to measly [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) (`2147483647`).

Following is the code from `Executors`

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

Default constructor in `LinkedBlockingQueue`

```
public LinkedBlockingQueue() {
    this(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
public LinkedBlockingQueue(int capacity) {
...
```

Option to create `ThreadPoolExecutor` directly still remains, however that's not much helpful. Lets examine that. Suppose we create `ThreadPoolExecutor` object using following code.

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(MAX_QUEUE_SIZE);
ThreadPoolExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAX_POOL_SIZE, IDLE_LIFE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
```

Where `MAX_QUEUE_SIZE` is 10. Number of maximum task that can be submitted can be found by following formula.

```
MAX_TASKS = MAX_POOL_SIZE + WORK_QUEUE_CAPACITY
```

So if max pool size is 10 and work queue size is also 10, then 21st task will be rejected, if no threads are free.

It's important to keep in mind that it doesn't give us desired behavior. As threads are only killed if there are more threads than `corePoolSize`. Thread pool increases more than `corePoolSize` only if `workQueue` has been exhausted.

**So `maxPoolSize` is a failsafe option to avoid queue exhaustion. Not the other way around. Max pool size is not intended to kill idle threads.**

If we set queue size too small, we risk task rejection. If we set it too high, `poolSize` will never cross `corePoolSize`.

May be you can explore [ThreadPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setRejectedExecutionHandler(java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler)). And save rejected task a separate queue which will send tasks to `workQueue` once `workQueue.capacity` becomes less than the max capacity periodically. But that seems a lot of work without equivalent gain.

Answer (score 0):

better to shutdown the executors once it's done.
it will release all the threads which are created with executor Service.

```
finally {
        if(!executors.isShutdown())
            executors.shutdown();
    }
```