# Runnable locked (park) using ExecutorService and BlockingQueue

Tags: java, executorservice, blockingqueue, linkedblockingqueue

**Note:** I understand the rules site, but I can't to put all code (complex/large code).

**I put a DIFFERENT** (*all the real code is too much and you don't need here*) **code in [Github](https://github.com/joseluisbz/ExecutorService_BlockingQueue_Problems.git) but reproduces the Problem** (the main class is `joseluisbz.mock.support.TestOptimalDSP` and switching class is `joseluisbz.mock.support.runnable.ProcessorDSP`) like the video.

*Please don't recommend to me another jar or external library for this code.*

I wish I was more specific, but I don't know what part to extract and show.
Before you close this question: Obviously, I am willing to refine my question if someone tells me where to look (technical detail).

I made a [video](https://youtu.be/KXLcR-N8qcY) in order to show my issue.

Even to formulate the question, I made a diagram to show the situation.

My program has a `JTree`, showing the relations between `Worker`.

[image]

I have a diagram interaction between threads controlling life with `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` and `List<Future<?>> listFuture = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());`

Each `Runnable` is started in this way `listFuture().add(executorService().submit(this));` in its constructor. The lists are created like this: `BlockingQueue<Custom> someBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();`

[image]

My diagram shows who the `Worker`'s father is if he has one.
It also shows, the writing relationships between the `BlockingQueue`.

`RunnableStopper` stops related runnables contained in `Worker` like property.
`RunnableDecrementer`, `RunnableIncrementer`, `RunnableFilter` operates with a cycle that runs each Custom that it receives for its `BlockingQueue`.
For which they always create a `RunnableProcessor` (it has no loop, but because of its long processing, once the task is finished it should be collected by the `GC`).

Internally the `RunnableIncrementer` has a Map `Map<Integer, List<Custom>> mapListDelayedCustom = new HashMap<>();//Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());`

When arrives some Custom... I need to obtain the List of lastReceivedCustom `List<Custom> listDelayedCustom = mapListDelayedCustom.putIfAbsent(custom.getCode(), new ArrayList<>());`
I'm controlling the Size (is not growing indefinitely).

My code stops working when I add the following lines:

```
if (listDelayedCustom.size() > SomeValue) {
  //No operation has yet been included in if sentence
}
```

But commenting the lines doesn't block

```
//if (listDelayedCustom.size() > SomeValue) {
//  //No operation has yet been included in if sentence
//}
```

[image]
**What could be blocking my Runnable?**
It makes no sense that adding the lines indicated (Evaluate the size of a list: `if sentence`) above stops working.

**Any advice to further specify my question?**

Comment: The context of your question isn't really clear to me. Would you be able to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @JacobG. Now, I'm uploading a video to show the problem because I don't know the cause, I don't know what code extract in order to repeat the problem ant put here. https://youtu.be/KXLcR-N8qcY (I need to wait 1 hour)

Comment: I can see why it would block if you were using `Collections#synchronizedMap`, but not if you were just using `HashMap`.

Comment: The result is the same, using `new HashMap<>();` or `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());`

Comment: ```Each Runnable is started in this way listFuture().add(executorService().submit(this)); in its constructor.``` 

Sounds like "leaking" reference, try to avoid this.
jfyi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851813/java-leaking-this-in-constructor

Comment: @Grigory Thank you for your recommendation, Already I Comment in its constructor `listFuture().add(executorService().submit(this));` by `SomeRunnable someRunnable = new SomeRunnable(blabla); listFuture().add(executorService().submit(someRunnable));` unfortunately The behaviour is same.

Comment: You'll need to share *a lot* more code than you have here; even the video barely shows any code - you scroll around for a bit and it's quite difficult to see the actual code; most of it is console output. With code this complicated, it's going to take serious debugging to ID the problem. I'm talking thread dumps and JFR; not something one can just glance at and prescribe a solution. Good luck anyway

Comment: Hi, I put all functional code reproducing the problem in github (taken from Netbeans). I was delayed by job and my personal project was delayed. I was reviewing but I can't find the problem.

Comment: @kolossus Late, but do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the way you set thread names is wrong. You use this pattern:

```
public class Test
{
    public static class Task implements Runnable
    {
        public Task()
        {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("Task");
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Task: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Thread(new Task()).start();
        System.out.println("Main: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

which gives the (undesired) result:

```
Main: Task
Task: Thread-0
```

It's incorrect because, in the `Task` constructor, the thread has not started yet, so you're changing the name of the calling thread, not the one of the spawned thread. You should set the name in the `run()` method.

As a result, the thread names in your screenshot are wrong.

Now the real issue. In [WorkerDSPIncrement](https://github.com/joseluisbz/ExecutorService_BlockingQueue_Problems/blob/master/src/joseluisbz/mock/support/runnable/WorkerDSPIncrement.java), you have this line:

```
List<ChunkDTO> listDelayedChunkDTO = mapListDelayedChunkDTO.putIfAbsent(chunkDTO.getPitch(), new ArrayList<>());
```

The documentation for [putIfAbsent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) says:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null) associates it with the given value **and returns null**, else returns the current value.

Since the map is initially empty, the first time you call `putIfAbsent()`, it returns `null` and assigns it to `listDelayedChunkDTO`.

Then you create a [`ProcessorDSP`](https://github.com/joseluisbz/ExecutorService_BlockingQueue_Problems/blob/master/src/joseluisbz/mock/support/runnable/ProcessorDSP.java) object:

```
ProcessorDSP processorDSP = new ProcessorDSP(controlDSP, upNodeDSP, null,
   dHnCoefficients, chunkDTO, listDelayedChunkDTO, Arrays.asList(parent.getParentBlockingQueue()));
```

It means you pass `null` as the `listDelayedChunkDTO` parameter. So when this line executes in `ProcessorDSP`:

```
if (listDelayedChunkDTO.size() > 2) {
```

it throws a `NullPointerException` and the runnable stops.

Comment: I see you also have an incorrect use of `putIfAbsent()` in [WorkerDSP](https://github.com/joseluisbz/ExecutorService_BlockingQueue_Problems/blob/master/src/joseluisbz/mock/support/WorkerDSP.java). And be aware that the second argument is always evaluated, even if the entry already exists! It means you will always create a `WorkerDSPPitchIncrement()` object, which is obviously not desired

Comment: I understand that according to the implementation it should not return null. [putIfAbsent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) `V v = map.get(key);
if (v == null) {
v = map.put(key, value);
}
return v;` **I changed to** `V v = map.get(key);
 if (v == null) {
  map.put(key, value);
  v = map.get(key);
 }
 return v;`

Comment: @joseluisbz [put()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) returns "null if there was no mapping for key", so it's expected behaviour.

Comment: What do you think what is better to use `List<ChunkDTO> listDelayedChunkDTO = new ArrayList<>();` or `List<ChunkDTO> listDelayedChunkDTO = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());` in *WorkerDSPDecrement*, *WorkerDSPFilter*, *WorkerDSPPitchIncrement* and `Map<Integer, WorkerDSPPitchIncrement> mapWorkerDSPPitchIncrement = new HashMap<>();`or `Map<Integer, WorkerDSPPitchIncrement> mapWorkerDSPPitchIncrement = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());` in *WorkerDSP*

Comment: @joseluisbz Well it depends if the collections are accessed concurrently or not. If only a single thread accesses them, then there is no reason to make them synchronized.